# Changing iOS App name in new update?

Tags: ios

I currently have an app which is in the iOS store, but in the new version I am wanting to change the entire name of the app with the upcoming update, with this what will I need to update?

The only things I can think of is the bundle ID & name in the developer centre, is that all?

Comment: You can't change the bundle id. If you do it won't be an update, it will be a new app.

Comment: If you change your bundle ID you can't update app. You can release app again with other name and Bundle ID but you can't change it after released.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the bundle ID since it's the same app.

I would suggest changing the name in the developer center, AND changing the "Bundle display name" in the plist. This will affect the name in the appstore as well as the name displayed under the app icon once it's installed on a device.

To change Bundle display name: Go to targets and select target. Select "Info" section. Under "Custom iOS target properties", add a new key with the name Bundle display name. Set value to new name.